# .htacces rewriteRule and rewriteCond not working correctly - why?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried the following to redirect to the php-script if the requested file exists and to redirect to the missed.php if it doesn't.
Why is it not working? It's always redirecting to the missed.php even if the file exists

```
########################## if file exists #########################
# get requested filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)$
# use filename from line above and see if filename.php exists
RewriteCond %1\.php -f
# page standalone && includes index.php
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
# page included in index.php
#RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [L]


#################### if file doesnt exits ################### 
# get requested filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)$   
# if filename.php doesnt exist
RewriteCond %1\.php !-f     
# redirect to missed.php
RewriteRule (.+) missed.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules instead as `REQUEST_FILENAME` won't work for non-existent file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ missed.php [L]
```

Comment: sadly it doesn't work either. now not even the files that exist want to work

Comment: This is tested and working code. What URL do you see in the browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: my url is: localhost/test/home and my .htaccess is in the root folder (test)

Comment: If .htaccess in in `/test/` folder then it is not called root. root is considered a directory above `/test/. Try my updated code now.

Comment: well it's working like it did before with mine but i've got the same problem: it always redirects to the missed.php file